# How to update Sort custom property "NewComparisonFlags"

Tags: ssis

When I am trying to run the package in production I'm facing this error:

```
The custom property "NewComparisonFlags" needs to be of type VT_I4.
```

"NewComparisonFlags" should be there in sort custom properties.

Comment: Describe the package, tell us what are you trying to put into `NewComparisonFlags`?

Comment: NewComparisonFlags as datatype VT_I4

Comment: What component should have this custom property? Does this package work on your machine and only fails on the production server? If so, what is different between the two systems?